# Avoid paragraf to be broken when using column-count in all browsers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, break

I'm doing some responsive design with columns with HTML5.
I'm stucked trying to make a single column for width<800px and 3 columns for a width>=800px.
I've done it with firefox, but can't do it with chrome and I.E. my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Media Queries Example 1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print">
    </head>
    <body>        
        <section>
            <div class="columns">
                <p>
                    <span class="pTitle">HTML:</span><br>
                    HTML, sigla en inglés de HyperText Markup Language 
                    (lenguaje de marcas de hipertexto), hace referencia al 
                    lenguaje de marcado para la elaboración de páginas web.
                    Es un estándar que sirve de referencia del software que 
                    conecta con la elaboración de páginas web en sus diferentes 
                    versiones, define una estructura básica y un código
                    (denominado código HTML) para la definición de contenido de 
                    una página web, como texto, imágenes, videos, juegos, entre otros.
                </p>

                <p>
                    <span class="pTitle">CSS:</span><br>
                    Hoja de estilo en cascada o CSS (siglas en inglés de cascading
                    style sheets) es un lenguaje usado para definir y crear la 
                    presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en HTML o 
                    XML2 (y por extensión en XHTML). El World Wide Web Consortium 
                    (W3C) es el encargado de formular la especificación de las 
                    hojas de estilo que servirán de estándar para los agentes de
                    usuario o navegadores.
                </p>

                <p>
                    <span class="pTitle">JAVASCRIPT:</span><br>
                    JavaScript (abreviado comúnmente JS) es un lenguaje de 
                    programación interpretado, dialecto del estándar ECMAScript.
                    Se define como orientado a objetos,3 basado en prototipos, 
                    imperativo, débilmente tipado y dinámico.<br>
                    Se utiliza principalmente en su forma del lado del cliente 
                    (client-side), implementado como parte de un navegador web 
                    permitiendo mejoras en la interfaz de usuario y páginas web 
                    dinámicas4 aunque existe una forma de JavaScript del lado 
                    del servidor (Server-side JavaScript o SSJS). 
                    Su uso en aplicaciones externas a la web, por ejemplo en 
                    documentos PDF, aplicaciones de escritorio (mayoritariamente
                    widgets) es también significativo.
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 800px){
    body{
        background: #ccccff;
    }

    div.columns{
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;

        -moz-column-gap: 40px;
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
        column-gap: 40px;

        -moz-column-rule: 5px solid black;
        -webkit-column-rule: 5px solid black;
        column-rule: 5px solid black;
    }

    div.columns p{
        page-break-inside:avoid;         
    }
}
```

This works PERFECT for FIREFOX (v44.02) but can't do it with chrome or I.E.
I've tried lots of css3 propierties but without luck.
Anyone knows a working method to do it for, at least, Firefox Chrome and Opera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your media query. You defined `(min-width: 1000px)` and not like you wrote for 800px width. For me it looks good in Chrome.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/o3gom4p2/

Comment: This is a minnor mistake, The main problem is not solved, I've tryied in some computers and same, so it's not working on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to the paragraphs you want to be displayed as one single unit of content.

Here's an updated jsfiddle based on Steffen's:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkazwkfa/

Comment: I've added display: inline-block and same behaviour in chrome, still break P.

Comment: Add a jsfiddle and I'll have a look... :-)